# starts with inside switch statement Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, switch-statement

```
when(message) {
    .startsWith("hey")
}
```

How do I check if my string starts with a certain word inside a switch statement in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `when` without an argument:

```kotlin
val msg = "This is some message"

when {
    msg.startsWith("This") -> println("Starts with This")
    msg.startsWith("That") -> println("Starts with That")
    else -> println("Doesn't start with This or That")
}
```

Output:

```
Starts with This
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow do it when( msg.startsWith) { "this" -> }? Because if I have a lot of cases it's tons of repetition.

Comment: A `when` might not be best choice in that case… It's not possible to use a function as argument in a `when()`, I think.

Comment: I managed to get it working, check my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

This is really interesting question.

Maybe something like that, lol?

```kotlin
run {
    operator fun String.unaryPlus() = "This is some message".startsWith(this)
    when {
        +"This" -> { println("Starts with This") }
        +"That" -> { println("Starts with That") }
        else -> { println("Doesn't start with This or That") }
    }
}
```

`run` is for operator overload localization

Of course you can use function or extension function instead of operator.

```kotlin
fun String.a() = "This is some message".startsWith(this)
when {
    "This".a() -> { println("Starts with This") }
    "That".a() -> { println("Starts with That") }
    else -> { println("Doesn't start with This or That") }
}
```

PS. And of course you can write all this as library code ))

```kotlin
class PredicateContext<T>(private val predicate: (T) -> Boolean) {
    operator fun T.invoke() = predicate(this)
}
```

... and use it anywhere

```kotlin
PredicateContext<String> { "This is some message".startsWith(it) }.run{
    when {
        "This"() -> println("Starts with This")
        "That"() -> println("Starts with That")
        else -> println("Doesn't start with This or That")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this and avoid the repetition, because when you provide an argument in `when (something)` the *something* is an *expression* that produces a value, which is fixed before the matching starts. And then your branch expressions are *compared* to that fixed value, trying to find an `equals` match (or a few other special cases, like `is` or `in`)

The closest you can get is what [*sirjoga* is going for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73775804/13598222), where you don't provide an argument to `when`, so the branch conditions are just simple boolean expressions. So instead of each condition being a value trying to match that *something* value, you make a function call that produces a *true* or *false* value, and the `when` block uses the first one that matches *true*.

---

If you really need to avoid the repetition while keeping it looking like a standard `when` matcher, you could do [something like this](https://pl.kotl.in/AFBrvkwHw):

```
fun <T, R> when2(
    predicate: (T) -> Boolean,
    matchers: Map<T, () -> R>,
    default: () -> R
) : R
{
    val match = matchers.entries.firstOrNull { predicate(it.key) }?.value ?: default
    return match.invoke()
}

fun main() {
    val thing = "this is a sentence"
    
    when2({ thing.startsWith(it) }, 
        mapOf(
           "this" to { println("Starts with this") },
           "that" to { println("Starts with that") }
        ), default = { println("uh oh") }   
    )
}
```

But then you're creating a `Map` each time it's called, instead of getting compiled neatly into some basic conditional code. You could [create a stateful object](https://pl.kotl.in/_QemxrX5L) (so you pass this all into the function call, but it stores it and returns an object that lets you do checks):

```
fun <T, R> whenMaker(
    matchers: Map<T, () -> R>,
    default: () -> R
) : ((T) -> Boolean) -> R
{
    return { predicate ->
        val match = matchers.entries.firstOrNull { predicate(it.key) }?.value ?: default
        match.invoke()
    }
}

fun main() {    
    val match = whenMaker(
        mapOf(
           "this" to { println("Starts with this") },
           "that" to { println("Starts with that") }
        ), default = { println("uh oh") }   
    )
    match { "this is a sentence".startsWith(it) }
    match { "that is a sentence".startsWith(it) }
    match { "them is a sentence".startsWith(it) }
}
```

But now you're separating the definition of your `when` structure from where it's actually used - especially as ideally, you wouldn't be creating that `match` object inside your function since that could happen repeatedly. But, depending on what you're doing and how much it matters, something like this could be useful! E.g. a convenience class that defines the `match` object in a top-level variable, directly above the function that makes use of it might not be so bad.

Comment: Yes it works, but this way we cannot use "return" inside variant lambdas. 

In most cases it doesn't matter.

Comment: @sirjoga oh yeah, if you want to control program flow like that, it's definitely simplest to just deal with the extra verbosity of writing `f("this")` or whatever. These are all workarounds for the limitations of `when`, they all have drawbacks! And sometimes doing things the standard way is best, just because it's familiar

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on how to do it without tons of repetition.
you can do it like this:

```
val str = "!settings change something"
val args = str.split(" ")

when (args[0]) {
    "!settings" -> TODO()
    "!other" -> TODO()
}
```

By doing it like this you don't have that much repetition because when having hundreds of cases you don't want to repeat writing msg.startsWith

Comment: OK, looks suitable for your situation but depends on `String` manipulation…